# Error with theapa and cedilla accent character: Illegal parameter number in definition of \B@my@dummy

Tags: bibliographies

I'm using `theapa` as bibliography style. If one of the references has an author with a cedilla accent under a character (i.e., `{\c e}` in the author name to produce an e with the accent), I obtain **the following error during compilation** (specifically, as produced by Overleaf):

```
Illegal parameter number in definition of \B@my@dummy.
    
<to be read again> 
                   \crcr 
l.11 \cite{Waledzik_2011_Multigame}
                                   
You meant to type ## instead of #, right?
Or maybe a } was forgotten somewhere earlier, and things
are all screwed up? I'm going to assume that you meant ##.
```

The **bib entry** as provided in a `References.bib` file is as follows:

```
@inproceedings{Waledzik_2011_Multigame,
    title           = "Multigame Playing by Means of {UCT} Enhanced with Automatically Generated Evaluation Functions",
    author          = "K. Wal{\c e}dzik and J. Ma{\'n}dziuk",
    booktitle       = "Artificial General Intelligence: 4th International Conference",
    volume          = "6830",
    series          = "Lecture Notes in Computer Science",
    pages           = "327--332",
    publisher       = "Springer",
    year            = "2011"
}
```

The full code of the .tex file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{theapa}

\title{Test}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\cite{Waledzik_2011_Multigame}

\bibliography{References}
\bibliographystyle{theapa}

\end{document}
```

An example project with this code, including the `theapa` files, can be found here: https://www.overleaf.com/read/qpxrgvjsptpv

Comment: your style is from 1997 and it uses `\edef` in places where it shouldn't. Why don't you use something more modern and maintained?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer This is what's included in the journal's author kit (download link on their formatting instructions page: https://jair.org/index.php/jair/formatting)

Comment: Then I would suggest that you complain to the journal. As it is the style is not suitable for authors with accents in their names. They should replace the \edef by \protected@edef.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Okay, I see, yeah if I do a full find and replace through the entire .sty file that fixes it. I'm not 100% sure if that's necessarily a good idea to do **everywhere**, or should it only be in some places? Either way, if you write it in an answer I can accept it.